# Incorrect output when calculating totals

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page where i am able to export a .csv file that is readable on excel. The invoice pulls the data from my database to calculate the total and grand total using the following columns:

```
quantity, packing_price, courier_price
```

I have noticed that my code doesn't output the correct answer when the prices contains a '£' sound in front of it. Is there a way that i could make this work for both number and currency data types?

**CODE:**

```
$output2= "";
$sql2 = mysql_query("
SELECT j.date
     , j.order_ref
     , j.quantity
     , j.packing_price
     , j.dispatch_type
     , j.courier_price 
  FROM Jobs j
 WHERE j.order_type = 'Retail International' 
   AND j.confirmed = 'Yes';
");
$columns_total2 = mysql_num_fields($sql2);

$total3 = "Total";
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total2; $i++)
{
    $heading2 = mysql_field_name($sql2, $i);
    $output2 .= '"'.$heading2.'",';
}

$output2 .= $total3;
$output2 .="\n";

$sum2 = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total2; $i++) {
        $output2 .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }

    $qty2 = $row['quantity'];
    $pack_price2 = $row['packing_price'];
    $dispatch2 = $row['courier_price'];
    $total2 =  (($qty2*$pack_price2) + $dispatch2);
    $total3 = $total2*1.2;
    $output2 .= $total3;
    $sum2 += $total3; // Add to overall total
    $output2 .="\n";

}
```

**Output:**
http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2014-07-03at113133_zpsbcc09900.png

Comment: What are the prices you get from the database? What is the output?

I think you should put some `echo` statements in between the lines. That should help.

Comment: What is the output of the code, and what is the correct answer?

Comment: @Krumia The information for the quantity, courier_price and packing_price outputs fine however the total and grand total is not giving the write answer.

Comment: @NisseEngström When i calculate manually for one row for example i should get a total of 20.35 but my code outputs 4.8

Comment: @user3519721: Check if individual totals are ok. And check if the grand total is correct with respect to the individual totals (even if they are wrong). _Note: Please improve your question by at least adding the output. Otherwise your question will be down-voted to oblivion._

Comment: @Krumia Thank you for the advice. I have added a link to my question which shows the current output

Comment: @user3519721: I can see that your grand total is correct with respect to subtotals. The output you posted is clearly not the output of the code snippet you provided.

Comment: @Krumia Apologies i have amended my question. I went through my code again and realised that the subtotals are correct for the prices that do not have a £ sign in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Code....

```
$output= "<table border='1' width='60%'><tr>";

$sql = " SELECT j.date ,
                j.order_ref ,
                j.quantity ,
                j.packing_price ,
                j.dispatch_type ,
                j.courier_price 
           FROM Jobs j
          WHERE j.order_type = 'Retail International' 
            AND j.confirmed = 'Yes' ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$total_columns = mysql_num_fields($query);

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_columns; $i++){
    $heading = mysql_field_name($query, $i);
    $output .= '<td>' . $heading . '</td>';

    if(($i+1) == $total_columns)  $output .= '<td>Total</td></tr>';
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $total_price = 0;

    $total_price =( ( $row['quantity'] * $row['packing_price'] ) + 
                      $row['courier_price'] );
    $total_price = $total_price * 1.2;
    $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s',  
                 $row['date'])->getTimestamp();
    $output .= '<tr>'; 
    $output .= '<td>' . date("d/m/Y", $timestamp) . '</td>';
    $output .= '<tr>'; 
    $output .= '<td>' . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['date']) . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $row['order_ref'] . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $row['quantity']. '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $row['packing_price'] . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $row['dispatch_type'] . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $row['courier_price'] . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td>' . number_format($total_price, 2) . '</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>'; 
}

$output .= "</table>";
echo '<br>' . $output;
```

Comment: I for some reason get a parser error on the .date("d/m/Y", ...) section

Comment: You can replace date("d/m/Y", ...) with DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s',  $row['date'])->getTimestamp();

Comment: Only the table headers are being displayed :S

Comment: did you create the database & Table and connect the database?

Comment: Yes i have created the database and table and connected to the database @Bireshwar